# Troubleshooting incorrect content on mobile redirect

Tags: php, redirect, apache2, laravel-8, subdomain

I own a domain called bigstore.com and have developed a Laravel website for it: [www.bigstore.com](http://www.bigstore.com). It's hosted on an Ubuntu 22.04 server utilizing Apache2, and the website is HTTPS-enabled. The server hosts both the domain (bigstore.com) and a subdomain (m.bigstore.com), intended for mobile browsers.

Here is the top-level directory for bigstore.com:

`/var/www/bigstore/`

Here is the top-level directory for m.bigstore.com:

`/var/www/m.bigstore/`

When a user enter [www.bigstore.com](http://www.bigstore.com) into his or her mobile browser, I purposely route it to m.bigstore.com. That works great for me. I know it works because if I put an index.html file with this content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Under the m.bigstore.com top-level directory here:

`/var/www/m.bigstore/public/index.html`

And then type [www.bigstore.com](http://www.bigstore.com) into my mobile browser; I see this:

```
My First Heading
My first paragraph
```

So that is PROOF that the traffic is being redirected correctly. However, when I DON'T USE the index.html file and instead use the m.bigstore.com index.php file as shown here:

`/var/www/m.bigstore/public/index.php`

Then, I type [www.bigstore.com](http://www.bigstore.com) into my mobile browser, and I see the content from my MAIN domain ([www.bigstore.com](http://www.bigstore.com)) Laravel site, NOT my SUBDOMAIN (m.bigstore.com) content! That's the problem. Specifically, I am seeing the content found in this file:

`/var/www/bigstore/resources/view/welcome.blade.php`  (which is under the main top-level directory)

When I should instead be seeing the content found in this file:

`/var/www/m.bigstore/resources/view/welcome.blade.php`  (which is under the subdomain top-level directory)

I think that index.php file under m.bigstore is causing the problem.

`/var/www/m.bigstore/public/index.php` has this content:

Here is its content:

```
 1   <?php
 2
 3   use Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel;
 4   use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 5
 6   define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));
 7
 8   if (file_exists($maintenance = __DIR__.'/../storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {require $maintenance;}
 9
10   require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
11
12   $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
13
14   $kernel = $app->make(Kernel::class);
15
16   $response = $kernel->handle($request = Request::capture())->send();
17
18   $kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

I suspect that the issue lies with Line 16 in the `index.php` file.

Specifically, `$kernel->handle($request = Request::capture())` seems to be generating content from the main domain.

Interestingly, while Line 16 is supposed to return a "/", it seems to be interpreted as the top-level of [www.bigstore.com](http://www.bigstore.com) rather than m.bigstore.com, which is puzzling. As I'm relatively new to this, I'm seeking clarification on what's happening in the `index.php` file.  If anyone could shed light on this issue or propose a solution, regardless of whether it involves the `index.php` file, I would greatly appreciate it.